# Is it possible to define setters for a Class in Swift

Tags: swift, combine, setter

I have created a version of `CurrentValueSubject` which can't be completed similar to `@Published`. However, I want to remove the need for `.send(value)` and define a setter for this class which will perform that.
Is that possible?

So from this:

```
customPublisher.send(newValue)
```

to this:

```
customPublisher = newValue
```

```swift
final class CustomPublisher<Output: Any>: Publisher {
    typealias Failure = Never

    var value: Output
    private var wrapper: CurrentValueSubject<Output, Failure>

    init(_ value: Output) {
        self.value = value
        wrapper = .init(value)
    }

    func send(_ value: Output) {
        self.value = value
        wrapper.send(value)
    }

    func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        wrapper.send(subscription: subscription)
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        wrapper.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}
```

Comment: `customPublisher = newValue`, this is not a setter but an assignment which is very different.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the syntax `customPublisher = newValue` to publish a new value, because in that syntax, you're putting a (perhaps entirely new) publisher into `customPublisher`.

You can make `customPublisher.value = newValue` work, though, just like `CurrentValueSubject` does. You need to make `value` a computed property with a setter, like this:

```
import Combine

final class CustomPublisher<Output: Any>: Publisher {
    private var wrapped: CurrentValueSubject<Output, Failure>

    typealias Failure = Never

    var value: Output {
        get { wrapped.value }
        set { wrapped.value = newValue }
    }

    init(_ value: Output) {
        wrapped = .init(value)
    }

    func send(_ value: Output) {
        wrapped.send(value)
    }

    func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        wrapped.send(subscription: subscription)
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        wrapped.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}
```